# disable submit input in html

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-input

When I tried this code the button input stays disabled even if there is a value in the input, why?

```
<form action ="/buy" method = "POST">
    <input id="symbol" type='text' name= 'symbol'/>
    <input id="shares" type= 'text' name = 'shares'/>
    <input id="submit" type= 'submit' disabled/>
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#shares').onkeyup = function(){
        if (document.querySelector('#shares').value === '') {
            document.querSelector('#submit').disabled = true;
        } else {
           document.querSelector('#submit').disabled = false;  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: typo : querSelector  > querySelector

Comment: With this code you could technically hold the `Backspace` key down, to empty the `input`, and then still submit an empty form. Ofcourse, this isn't something a legitimite user would do, but it is possible.

Comment: Agree with @Daan - you should really be testing for onchange for the field as well as checking to see if it still has a value. Answer below is for what you asked though.

Comment: I just started HTML and the synatx is new to me so the issue was with the synatx as you said,Thanks!!!

Comment: Please undo the edit that you made to the question, its misleading anyone else that comes here  looking for answers as now code in answer is same as in question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is right apart from this statement in else, you have an error with syntax

```
<form action ="/buy" method = "POST">
    <input id="symbol" type='text' name= 'symbol'/>
    <input id="shares" type= 'text' name = 'shares'/>
    <input id="submit" type= 'submit' disabled/>
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#shares').onkeyup = function(){
        if (document.querySelector('#shares').value === '') {
            document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
        } else {
           document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akcvtf2r/

Comment: typo: document.querSelector('#submit').disabled = true;  "y" missing in "querSelector" !

Comment: Good spot! Updated answer